# HTTP 413 Request Entity Too Large In Self-Hosting WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, https, self-hosting

I have a self-hosting WCF service accepting messages via HTTPS.

A message is being sent from a Java application, which receives the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 09:05:34 GMT
Connection: close
```

I am not attempting to upload a file, just send an XML/SOAP message, which is 78kb. I have tried upping my max message and buffer sizes but to no avail.

```
  <binding name="SecuredNoProxy" openTimeout="00:00:10" sendTimeout="00:00:10">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
      <security includeTimestamp="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="true">
          <localClientSettings timestampValidityDuration="00:15:00" />
      </security>
      <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="false" requireClientCertificate="true" />
  </binding>
```

Please let me know if I can supply any additional information.

**WCF Trace Log**

> Receive bytes on connection 'https://localhost'
>
> Activity boundary (Start)
>
> Connection information
>
> Throwing an exception (Error)

The exception is:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Comment: Enable [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.100).aspx) to see if the message is being processed by WCF or not. That message looks like its coming from the HTTP host component, not the WCF plumbing.

Comment: @SixtoSaez - I have added the WCF trace log information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I eluded to in the question, this is very much related to the binding configurations. In particular, maxReceivedMessageSize.

```
maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
```

This is the correct area to change (probably not to make things quite this big though as it will leave you potentially vulnerable to denial of service attacks). Determine a sensible value based on your actual messages.

The outbound endpoint was correctly configured but the inbound endpoint wasn't - it was:

```
<httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
```

Which meant it was using the default value of `65536`, which isn't enough for the message being sent. So it is really a case of checking the endpoints really carefully, especially if they are similarly named.

Comment: Steve I know it's been a while since you answered this, but could you elaborate on what you meant by outbound vs. inbound endpoints? Thanks.

Comment: It is all a bit of a haze. Thank goodness for lightweight REST services I haven't had to look at this kind of thing for a while. Despite this, I meant "outbound" = "the service" and "inbound" = "the caller" (I think!)

Answer (score 2):

For me it was maxRequestLength under system.web:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime
        maxRequestLength="2147483647"
        executionTimeout="300" />
</system.web>
```